# Properties of a bilinear mapping and its associated matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this exercise that I do not know how to solve it, someone could help me?

Let $E=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the euclidean norm $| \cdot |$. Prove that

1. $a\colon E\times E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bilinear map if and only if exists an unique real matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j}$ where $i,j=1,\dots, n$ such that $a(u,v)=(Au,v)$ for any $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the canonical scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$;
2. If the map $a\colon E\times E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bilinear map then is also continuous;
3. Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $(Au,u)>0$ for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}-\{0\}$. Then $A$ is invertible;
4. Show that the inverse implication of the previous point does not hold.

For the last point I got it. Is enough to take the following counterexample

\begin{equation}
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
 1 & 5 \\
1 & -1
\end{matrix}\right), \quad u=\left(\begin{matrix}
-3 \\
7
\end{matrix}\right).
\end{equation}
$A$ is invertible and $(Au,u)=-306<0$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your very terse (sorry) "linear algebra exercice" into something more significant. This is important for querying in such a huge site.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ be the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We define
$$A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j}=(a(e_{j},e_{i}))_{i,j}$$
Now let let $u=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\lambda_{i}e_{i},v=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\mu_{i}e_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and note that
$$a(u,v)=\sum^{n}_{j=1}\sum^{n}_{i=1}\lambda_{i}\mu_{j}a(e_{i},e_{j})=\sum^{n}_{j=1}\mu_{j}\sum^{n}_{i=1}\lambda_{i}a_{j,i}=(Au,v).$$
The other direction is evident.

For 2 use that $A$ and the scalar product are both continuous linear/bilinear maps.

For 3 consider what it means for $A$ to be invertible with respect to the eigenvalues of $A$.

Finally for 4 the counterexample works, but you might want to consider using a simpler example like $A=(-1)$ and $u=(1)$ for $E=\mathbb{R}$. Again it is all about the eigenvalues.

Comment: About the point $3$ I think I could argue that if $(Au,u)>0$ the matrix has to be invertible, because of the non negativity on the determinant. I would say that if the matrix $A$ is invertible $(Au,u)$, with $u \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, has to be either positive or negative. Am I right?

Comment: This need not be the case. Consider for example $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then for $u\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ we have $(Au,u)=0$, but $A$ is invertible. Also for  $B=\begin{pmatrix}1 &  0 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ we find that $(Be_{1},e_{1})=1$ and $(Be_{2},e_{2})=-1$, for $e_{1},e_{2}$ the standard basis vectors. Both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Comment: Hence I do not get it... can you explain how can I prove it?

Comment: First of all, you only have to prove one direction, so you don't have to prove that if a matrix is invertible, then $(Au,u)>0$ for all $u$. You just have to prove that if $(Au,u)>0$, then $A$ is invertible. If $(Au,u)>0$ for all $u$, then clearly $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$, hence $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I noticed that the matrix $B$ you used in the above example is not invertible, in fact one eigenvalue is $0$.

Comment: That's a typo, it should have been $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.